# Which Visual Studio for mac do I need for Xamarin.iOS: Community, Pro, or enterprise

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The tutorial Setup and Install Visual Studio for Mac step one is to:
"Download Visual Studio for Mac from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/"
..but it doesn't declare which VS supports Xamarin:  Community, Professional, or Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this [chart](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) (expand "Cross Platform"), all versions of VS (Windows and Mac) support Xamarin.  Some of the advanced tools are only available with the higher level editions.

Comment: Funny:  At Mac I selected VS Pro but it installed Community.